# Computing the Madelung constant

Tags: python

I am **self teaching** myself python and computational physics via Mark Newmans book Computational Physics the exercise is 2.9 of Computational Physics I have to compute the [Madelung](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_constant) constant. [image].

I have **two different solutions** worked out I wanted to know which code is correct and is there a way to exclude **0** in my range so I don't have to write two separate for loops. I think my second answer is correct can somebody verify.

**My first answer:**

```
M = 0

for i in range(-200,0):
    for j in range(-200,0):
        for k in range(-200,0):

            M += ((-1)**(i+j+k))/((i**2 + j**2 + k**2)**(1/2))

print(M)           
for i in range(1,200):
    for j in range(1,200):
        for k in range(1,200):

            M += ((-1)**(i+j+k))/((i**2 + j**2 + k**2)**(1/2)) 

print(M)
```

**My second answer:**

```
M = 0
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0
for l in range(-200,0):
    i = l
    j = l
    k = l
    M += ((-1)**(i+j+k))/((i**2 + j**2 + k**2)**(1/2))

print(M)

for l in range(1,200):
    i = l
    j = l
    k = l
    M += ((-1)**(i+j+k))/((i**2 + j**2 + k**2)**(1/2))

print(M)
```

Comment: This seems like a question for either [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) or… is there a computational physics StackExchange? Or does it just belong on Physics? I'm not sure. Read their help, especially [on-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); if it fits better there, you can flag your own question to ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: Anyway, if this _is_ a StackOverflow question, then it has to explain what you mean by "correct" in some way that makes sense to a programming expert, not a physics expert. Where do the two differ?

Comment: @ abarnert I was not sure since it involved programing if it was a purely physics based question and would be relevant there, for your second part comment I would like someone to explain which of the two is correct in the sense why one answer is correct not merely if it is right or wrong

Comment: Well, I explained the difference between the two, but I don't know which one matches what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the code (in C, though) for the kind of loop you can write:

```
  for (int n = 1; n <= L; n++) {
    for (int i = -n; i <= n; i++) {
      for (int j = -n; j <= n; j++) {
        for (int k = -n; k <= n; k++) {
          if (abs(i) != n && abs(j) != n && abs(k) != n)
            continue;

          // Your update to the potential energy goes here.
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Observe that this loop iterates over cubic shells of radius $n$.  This is the way to properly compute the Madelung constant (see Section III of [1] for details).

[1] Borwein, D., Borwein, J. M., & Taylor, K. F. (1985). Convergence of lattice sums and Madelung’s constant. Journal of Mathematical Physics, 26(11), 2999. doi:10.1063/1.526675

Answer (score 3):

There *is* a huge, obvious difference between the two.

The first one loops over every combination of negative `i, j, k` values, and every combination of positive `i, j, k` values. The second only loops over `i == j == k` values. So, for example, the first one has `-200, -200, -200`, then `-200, -200, -199`, and so on to `-200, -200, -1`, then `-200, -199, -200`, and so on; the second just goes right from `-200, -200, -200` to `-199, -199, -199`.

But I have no idea which one is correct or how to verify it, because that's a physics question, not a Python question.

---

Meanwhile, there is a Python question hidden in there:

> is there a way to exclude 0 in my range so I don't have to write two separate for loops.

Sure. You want an iterable over all the values in `range(-200, 0)` and all the values in `range(1, 200)`. You can do that by just [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)ing the two iterables together:

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.chain(range(-200, 0), range(1, 200)):
    print(i)
```

Or, if you prefer, just merge them manually and explicitly skip the 0:

```
for i in range(-200, 200):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    print(i)
```

---

By the way, are you sure you wanted `range(1, 200)`, not `range(1, 201)`? It seems strange that `-200` is inside the set of values, but `200` isn't. But maybe that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

I am working through the same book to teach myself Python. My working code is:

```
from math import *
from numpy import *


M = 0.0 #set a float variable for Madelung Constant
L = int(input("Enter the size of the crystal lattice L/2: "))

for x in range(-L, L+1):
  for y in range(-L, L+1):
      for z in range(-L, L+1):
          if x == y == z == 0:
              continue
          r = (x**2 + y**2 + z**2)**-0.5
          if x + y + z%2 == 0:
            M = M+r
          else:
            M = M-r
          print(x, y, z)
print(M)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
from math import sqrt,pi

e = 1.602e-19 #Coloumbs
epsNaught = 8.85e-12 #F/m
M = 0 #Madelung constant, total potential felt by origin sodium atom
n = 0 #Number of atoms

#lattice size
L = int(input("Enter lattice size: "))

#spacing of atoms
a = int(input("Distance between atoms: "))

for i in range(-L,L+1):
    for j in range(-L,L+1):
        for k in range(-L,L+1):
            n += 1
            distance = a * sqrt(i**2 + j**2 + k**2)

            if (i == j == k == 0): #Case for soidium atom at origin
                continue

            potential = e / (4 * pi * epsNaught * distance)

            if (i+j+k)%2 == 1: #Odd, chlorine atoms, attraction = neg potential
                potential *= -1

            M += potential

print("Madelung constant:",M,"due to",n-1,"atoms.")`
```

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia cites ±1.747565 for NaCl.  The following code gives
For L = 200 M = -1.7446850421707383

```
# madelung.py: compute the Madelung constant for sodium chloride
from math import sqrt
L = int(input("Enter L: "))
M = 0.0
for i in range(-L, L + 1):
   for j in range(-L, L + 1):
      for k in range(-L, L + 1):
         if i == j == k == 0:
            continue
         M += (-1)**(i+j+k) / sqrt( i*i + j*j + k*k )
print("For L =", L, "M =", M)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).