# Is this the correct way to calculate the Madelung constant?

Tags: computational-physics

I'm trying to compute the [Madelung constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_constant) of the ZnS lattice.
The method is as follows:
The lattice is a face-centered-cubic with basis $S^-: (0,0,0)$ and $Zn^+: (1/4,1/4,1/4)$.
The Madelung constant is
$$\alpha=\sum_j \frac{q_j}{r_j}$$
where $q_j$ is the charge (in this case divided by the number of neighboring blocks) of $j$
and $r_j$ the distance to a fixed ion.
Evjen's method tells us that we need to form blocks of neutral charge to obtain a good
convergence.

I've chosen to start with two cubes and the origin is placed in the center of the face that 
is common to both cubes (so I have a block of size 1x1x2).
Then, two get more precision I add two cubes in each direction (so in the second iteration
I have a block of size 3x3x4).

The problem is that this method converges to $\alpha\approx 5.35$, when it should be $\alpha\approx 1.64$.
**Is this the correct block expansion?**  I've tried with other block and I get the same value.

I haven't included the code, because I think that the problem is in the block chosen.

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate of http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/19780/15

Comment: @JuanM.Bello-Rivas I don't think so, because the ZnS has different structure than NaCl. For example the CsCl blocks have to be dodecahedron, not cubes.